# Bootstrap-styl npm module gives stylus compiler error during Meteor app build

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, stylus

The Stylus compiler built in the Meteor.js builder gives me the following error:

```
cannot perform $line-height-computed * 0.75
   at ".table-responsive"
   ({}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/tables.styl:147:1)
```

during the build while attempting to compile the `tables.styl` file of the `bootstrap-styl` npm module that I added in my Meteor app.

Any idea what the problem might be?
I am using:

- meteor 1.4.2.3 on OS X El Capitan
- bootstrap stylus 3.3.7 added to my app by doing

  meteor npm install bootstrap-styl
- and the following files from this module:

  import button from '/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/js/button.js'

  @import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/tables.styl'

  @import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/mixins/table-row.styl'

  @import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/buttons.styl'

  @import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/mixins/table-row.styl'

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been an import order problem.

Now that I have:

```
@import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/variables'
@import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/mixins/table-row'
@import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/tables'
@import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/mixins/buttons'
@import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap-styl/bootstrap/buttons'
```

the compiling error is gone.